# Problems with reciprocal of an dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

given dict: `weights = {"A":16, "B": 3, "C": 5)`
I want to have the reciprocal of the values.

Output:
`weights_dict_reci = {"A":0,0625, "B": 0,3333333, "C": 0,2)`

So far I tried:
`weights_dict_reci = {value: 1 / weights_dict[value] for value in weights_dict}`

and

```
for key in weights_dict:
    weights_dict[key] = 1 / weights_dict[key]
```

Everytime i get the error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'

1st: How to make tke reciprocal for the dict values?

2nd: what is the cause for this error in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Python version 3.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to work fine on my version of Python (but you have syntax errors from the start in your question).

```
weights_dict = {"A":16, "B": 3, "C": 5}
weights_dict_reci = {value: 1 / weights_dict[value] for value in weights_dict}
print( weights_dict )
print( weights_dict_reci )
```

Output:

```
{'A': 16, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}
{'A': 0.0625, 'B': 0.3333333333333333, 'C': 0.2}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your *Minimum Reproducible Example* your dictionary is **`weights`**.

You can try:

```
weights = {"A":16, "B": 3, "C": 5}

{k:1/v for k,v in weights.items()}
```

---

Alternatively, as you tried in your attempt:

```
{value: 1 / weights[value] for value in weights}  # here value is the `key` for the dictionary `weights`.
```

---

output

```
#{'A': 0.0625, 'B': 0.3333333333333333, 'C': 0.2}
```

I am not sure about `weights_dict` as you have not provided any information about it.

From the error, it looks like `weights_dict[value]` is a function somewhere in your code.